# Syntax highlighting for source code of urdf & sdf (xml-based) files on Github

Tags: ros, gazebo

Note: I posted this on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61535005/syntax-highlighting-for-source-code-of-urdf-xml-based-file-on-github) but couldn't get an answer. I am trying it here.

I have files that are in `urdf` [Unified Robot Description Format] for `ROS` and `sdf` [Simulation Description Format] for `gazebo`. URDF is `xml` but Github only shows it in black. How can I get Github to show syntax highlighting on the file? Can I do this for any file extension including a missing extension?

**NOTE:** I am not referring to comments in markdown so back ticks don't apply.

```
<sdf version='1.6'>
  <world name='default'>

    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>

    <include>
      <pose frame=''>0 0 30 0 0 0</pose>
      <uri>model://robot</uri>
    </include>

...


  </world>
</sdf>
```

Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting seems to get it.

Comment: I would suggest that you reach out to GitHub support and request that they add detection and syntax highlighting of the file format.

Comment: On stack exchange, comments are not intended for extended discussions, they are for helping to improve questions and answers. Comments are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. They should be considered ephemeral, any comment which no longer actively helps to improve a question or answer may be deleted at any time to *tidy up* a post. For extended discussion on a question or answer, please use [chat] when you have [chat privileges](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).

Answer (score 2):

The [GitHub page on code blocks](https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks) has a section on [syntax highlighting](https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks#syntax-highlighting) that says:

> ## Syntax highlighting
>
> You can add an optional language identifier to enable syntax highlighting in your fenced code block.
>
> For example, to syntax highlight Ruby code:
>
> ````
> ```ruby
> require 'redcarpet'
> markdown = Redcarpet.new("Hello World!")
> puts markdown.to_html
> ```
> ````
>
> [image: github highlighting]

More information is provided below that example:

> We use [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) to perform language detection and to select [third-party grammars](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/vendor/README.md) for syntax highlighting. You can find out which keywords are valid in [the languages YAML file.](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml)

In reviewing the [third-party grammars](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/vendor/README.md) it looks like URDF specifically isn't included, but XML is. Since the URDF "[is an XML format for representing a robot model,](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf)" I'd just tag the block as XML.

:EDIT:

Just re-read and you say you're asking about files, not comments, but I checked a URDF file [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/robot_movement_interface/blob/master/dependencies/ur_description/urdf/ur10_robot.urdf) and it looks like the following for me:

[image: URDF markup]

If there's some other issue you've got please link a specific example where it's not working for you.